# Collision Paradox time inversion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, time, collision

I am currently working on an physics engine to simulate collisions of balls.
I have one blue and one red ball, the red ball moves forward in time, while the blue one moves backwards in time.

Basically a very simplified version of the movie Tenet (the inspiration i got).

My question: if those balls move directly at each other and collide ellastic, what will happen? My intuition says they will bounce back since energy and momentum has to be preseved, but the blue ball receives additional energy by hitting the red ball, since its time is backwards. On the other hand the red ball should also gain energy cancelling each other out. So will those balls stick together and loose all their energy? Or will they gain additional energy after collision?

I know its a more Sci-Fi physics but the laws of physics should work in both directions of time. Maybe there is an answer to that. I would be very thankfull to any advise or help to that problem.

Comment: You seem to be confusing elasticity with momentum transfer.    Further, are you going to accept that the only things which travel backwards in time are anti-particles (as Feynman suggested), or are you creating "magic" to allow normal mass to reverse time?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - **[read this great resource](https://www.myphysicslab.com/engine2D/collision-methods-en.html)** on this topic to understand all the issues with modeling collisions using software.

Comment: @JAlex I suspect you meant to aim that comment at Miai

Answer (score 1):

The physics of the balls' motion and collision is exactly the same. All you are doing is picking the boundary conditions differently.

Conservation of energy and momentum create relations between the initial motions and final motions of the two balls. Our usual approach is to specify the initial motions and use the relations to calculate the final motions. But it is perfectly legitimate to specify final motions and ask what initial motions would have led to that result, or even (as you are doing) to specify one initial and one final motion, and calculate the other two to fit.

If you play video of an elastic collision, it looks the same whether you play it forwards or backwards in time. In classical mechanics, time reversal just negates all the velocities.

It's almost the same calculation billiards player do when planning a shot. They know what the final trajectory they want the target ball to take is going to be. How should they hit the cue ball to bring it about? Given the desired end state, what are the initial conditions?

Elastic collisions and frictionless motion is relatively easy. You might have problems with inelastic collisions, and friction is probably worse, since the time-reversal of a billiard ball rolling to a halt is billiard balls spontaneously starting to move at arbitrary times. It might be an interesting topic to investigate, though.

Kip Thorne, in his book 'Black Holes and Time Warps', describes how they modelled billiard ball collisions in the context of time-travelling wormholes. They were trying to construct a version of the 'grandfather paradox' amenable to analysis, and hit on the idea of potting a ball into a wormhole on such a trajectory that it would pop out of the other end in the past, and hit itself, deflecting it from the hole so it never reached the first wormhole. Analysis showed that there was always a slightly different trajectory for the ball to hit itself, and still fall in the wormhole, the deflection putting it onto the modified trajectory necessary. So the paradox could be avoided. (In fact, there were usually infinitely many such trajectories, and the problem was not knowing which it would pick.) You might find it interesting/inspiring.

Comment: I'm not (yet) convinced you can claim to use classical mechanics when **only one of the two** balls is undergoing time-reversal.